# Are there countries where I shouldn't offer to shake hands with people of the opposite sex?

Tags: local-customs, socializing, cultural-awareness

I've known for a while that some people avoid shaking hands with people of the opposite sex. I don't know whether it's purely based on religion, nationality, or whether personal preference also plays a role.

Are there some countries in which I shouldn't offer to shake hands with people of the opposite sex, even if I am socialising with them? If so, are there substitutes for hand-shaking?

Comment: Voted to close, since it is to broad and at least a shopping question

Comment: @andra shopping question? It's possible to pay women to be able to shake their hand?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: And if you really want to know, wikipedia has an elaborate article on the matter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake

Comment: @andra: as well as pasting it, try reading it: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping

Comment: The question, in a more specific form and from a different perspective has been asked [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5487).

Comment: You shouldn't offer to shake hands with Muslims of the opposite sex regardless of the country.